# Physically attacked by a resident of a group home

Tags: work-environment, united-states, conflict, time-off

I work in a [group home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_home) in Virginia, USA. Yesterday, my coworker and I were both physically attacked by a resident, who is a minor. The attack lasted around 45 minutes until the police arrived, and it took our program manager even longer to arrive.

We were not given any time off unless we wanted to use our own Paid Time Off (PTO). Because I did not want to use my PTO, I had to go back to work today and work with this client.

What are my legal rights in Virginia for situations like this? What do other mental health agencies do when staff is attacked?

Comment: What is VA? And what locality do this occur?

Comment: In the United States-Virginia

Comment: Probably better ask this to your manager or union if you have one, legal questions are considered off topic here.

Comment: We’re you injured in the attack? If so, did you go to a doctor or hospital?

Comment: `What are my legal rights in Virginia for situations like this?` - Consult an attorney.

Comment: Related question: [Being attacked by a client in my workplace - what are my rights?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/90243/being-attacked-by-a-client-in-my-workplace-what-are-my-rights/90385#90385)

Comment: Hi, and welcom to workplace.SE! Some details of your question are not clear, such as your work situation. I tried to edit to clarify - please review and re-edit as appropriate.

Comment: Also: Please add what your role in the group home is. Are you a doctor, a therapist, social worker, nurse...? What are your responsibilities, in particular with respect to the person who attacked you?

Comment: And finally - while your problem is on-topic here, we need a clear, concrete question with a goal. Just asking for information does not work well here. Please edit to explain what your goal is (get time off, get support when working with the problematic client, sue your employer, whatever...). We cannot help you if we do not understand what you want / need.

Comment: @joeqwerty: While consulting an attorney may be reasonable, it can be costly. General legal advice is on-topic here (see e.g. [What is asking for legal advice?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice) ), so I think it's problematic to just reply with "ask a lawyer", especially with a new user who may feel they are being sent away.

Comment: @sleske I disagree that advising the OP to seek legal counsel is bad advice or is a brush off. He clearly is asking what his legal rights are and so that can only be authoritatively answered by an attorney. It may be that general legal advice is on topic here, but I personally would take any "legal" advice here as anecdotal (at best) and not authoritative. Contrary to your opinion of my comment, I think I've given the OP sound advice. Seek an attorney who can answer authoritatively.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Virginia law pertaining to the protection of mental health employees from violence by patients in mental health institutions, and codified at [this link](https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title54.1/chapter24/section54.1-2400.1/), the degree of liability of your employer depends on whether they knew **or should have known** whether a particular patient is likely to be violent, or has made threats previously. The relevant quote is as follows from section B:

> A mental health service provider has a duty to take precautions to protect third parties from violent behavior or other serious harm only when the client has orally, in writing, or via sign language, communicated to the provider a specific and immediate threat to cause serious bodily injury or death to an identified or readily identifiable person or persons, if the provider reasonably believes, or should believe according to the standards of his profession, that the client has the intent and ability to carry out that threat immediately or imminently.

Therefore, the degree to which you can legally recover would depend to what extent your employer is forewarned about the demeanor of this particular patient.  If you had any previous interactions with this particular person, **documentation of their language, conduct, and / or mannerisms would be your best friend to help evidence that this particular person has exhibited threatening / violent behavior in the past**. Hence the part on where employer **should have known** comes into effect.

If your employer did not warn you about such possible violence from this patient and they should have **reasonably** known about it, they probably did not meet their degree of due care required under the law to avoid liability under section C (2). Again, documentation (or the lack thereof) if your friend here.